# Nativescript ButtonDown event

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm working on an app using Angular 2+ and Nativescript 5. In a normal button I listen to "taps" with the tap event:

```
<Button text="Tap me" (tap)="onTap($event)"></Button>
```

But the tap event triggers after the finger releases the button.

Now I want to listen to the "ButtonDown" event, when the finger touches the button. But I can't find that event on the docs!

Is there any workaround that works in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to listen for the [touch](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-ui-widgets/gestures#touch) event and make sure the action is `down`.